# Not able to compare if  username exist in database or not

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am new to android. I want to compare username from database to an entered value from an activity, and getting a NullPointerException (NPE).

Here is my DBHElper activity

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID1="_id";
    public static final String KEY_FNAME = "firstname";
    public static final String KEY_LNAME = "lastname";
    public static final String KEY_GENDER = "gender";
    public static final String KEY_USER = "username";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String KEY_CNAME="Cname"; 
    public static final String KEY_CPOST="Cpost"; 
    public static final String KEY_CCRITERIA="Ccriteria"; 
    public static final String KEY_CUSER="Cusername"; 
    public static final String KEY_CEMAIL="Cemail"; 
    public static final String KEY_CCONTACT="Ccontact"; 
    public static final String KEY_CCUTOFF="Ccutoff"; 

    public static final String KEY_STATUS="status";
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME="username";


    DBHelper DB = null;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Sam2.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_NAME = "JobSeeker";
    public static final String Company_Table = "Comp";
    public static final String Login_Table = "Login";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
        "firstname TEXT NOT NULL, lastname TEXT NOT NULL, gender TEXT NOT NULL, username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, password TEXT NOT NULL, email TEXT NOT NULL);";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE2=
        " create table " + Company_Table +
        " (_id integer primary key autoincrement," +
        " Cname TEXT NOT NULL, Cpost TEXT NOT NULL,Ccriteria TEXT NOT NULL,Cusername TEXT NOT NULL, Cpassword TEXT NOT NULL, Cemail TEXT NOT NULL,Ccontact TEXT NOT NULL,Ccutoff TEXT NOT NULL);" ;
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE3=
        "CREATE TABLE " + Login_Table  + "(" +
        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
        "username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, password TEXT NOT NULL, status TEXT NOT NULL);";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
      System.out.println("In constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try{
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE2);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE3);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public Cursor rawQuery(String string, String[] strings) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void open() {
        getWritableDatabase(); 
    }

    public Cursor getDetails(String text) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, 
                  new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_FNAME, KEY_LNAME, KEY_GENDER, KEY_USER, KEY_EMAIL}, 
                  KEY_USER + "=" + text, 
                  null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) 
        {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public Cursor getCompDetails(String text) throws SQLException 
    {

        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, Company_Table, 
                  new String[]{KEY_ROWID1, KEY_CNAME, KEY_CPOST, KEY_CCRITERIA, KEY_CUSER, KEY_EMAIL,KEY_CCONTACT,KEY_CCUTOFF}, 
                  KEY_CUSER + "=" + text, 
                  null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) 
        {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public Cursor getLoginDetails(String text) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, Login_Table, 
                  new String[]{KEY_ROWID1, KEY_USERNAME, KEY_STATUS}, 
                  KEY_USERNAME + "=" + text, 
              null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) 
        {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public Boolean checkusername(String name) throws SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(
                  Login_Table, 
                  new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_USERNAME }, 
                  KEY_USERNAME + "=?", 
                  new String[] {name}, 
                  null, 
                  null, 
                  null);
        if (mCursor!=null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the activity where the comparison is performed.

```
DB.open();
if (DB.checkusername(uname)) {
    invalid = true;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
          "username alredy in use enter another", 
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

its showing error in this line

```
   Cursor mCursor = db.query(
              Login_Table, 
              new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_USERNAME }, 
              KEY_USERNAME + "=" + name, 
              null, 
              null, 
              null, 
              null);
```

here is logcat

```
07-07 23:52:56.813: W/dalvikvm(536): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-07 23:52:56.823: E/AndroidRuntime(536): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 23:52:56.823: E/AndroidRuntime(536): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-07 23:52:56.823: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at com.google.data.DBHelper.checkusername(DBHelper.java:164)
07-07 23:52:56.823: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at com.google.data.Registration.onClick(Registration.java:211)
07-07 23:52:56.823: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-07 23:52:56.823: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-07 23:52:56.823: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-07 23:52:56.823: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-07 23:52:56.823: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-07 23:52:56.823: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-07 23:52:56.823: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 23:52:56.823: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-07 23:52:56.823: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-07 23:52:56.823: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-07 23:52:56.823: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Alright OP! Two answers here have asked you the same thing - we think `db` and/or `DB` was not instantiated at all as in `db = new ...` in fact, we don't know what object type is that at all! Please amend your code to include more info?

Comment: I still can't find where You assing something to 'db'. You should assign to db what getWritableDatabase() returns.

Comment: OP: Please re-format your code in future to save us the hassle in having to re-edit your question to tidy up your code for others!

Comment: Downvoting for showing very little effort and lack of research.

Comment: hey @tomm13b can u please edit my code where to put db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext()); because its giving some error..!! plz

Comment: Oo - huh, I beg your pardon, we're not here to write code on your behalf.

Comment: Downvoting: you can find a LOT of examples to start with!!! just follow one of them! NO ONE WILL WRITE A FULL MODULE for you.

Comment: ohkk now m getting it wat u wr saying i have already assign 
DBHelper DB = new DBHelper(Registration.this); globally in my Registration.class where comaprison is done.
its no use

Answer (score 0):

Username is of type string, so you need to compare it like **'*name*'**

Try this:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ Login_Table + " WHERE "+ 
KEY_USERNAME + "='" + name + "'";
```

**EDIT:**
After full code is provided.

The rawQuery should work, but the db(SQLiteDatabase) is not initialized anyhwre, so it will always remain NULL.

Comment: It looks like the issue is some where else... The Query looks OK to me. Can you check that the db is not NULL?

Comment: no! not the database - what Yaqub Ahmad meant is the variable 'db', is that null?

Comment: Have you checked the above query? i mean rawQuery not worked for you? can you tell me what the LogCat says?

Comment: i have given the logcat above check it and how to check if my db is null? will i upload whole DBhelper class???

Comment: you can simply try:
if(db == null)
{
  Log.i("someTAG","Error .. DB IS NULL"); 
}

Comment: @YaqubAhmad i have intalised it alredy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, instead of using `=`, use `LIKE`

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query(
              Login_Table, 
              new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_USERNAME }, 
              KEY_USERNAME + " LIKE '" + name + "'", 
              null, 
              null, 
              null, 
              null);
```

**Edit:** Actually, scratch that, my human compiler is failing me, is `db` instantiated within the method `checkusername`? If it is not, `db` is null and thus NPE occurs when attempting to invoke `query`.

**Edit#2:** Right, now the OP has provided more info, it turns out that the vital instantiation of the variable is missing as in for example:

```
db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
```

then it should work without any NPE error.

Comment: @Yaqub Ahmad: Thanks for the quick edit, as I said my human compiler is failing due to sweltering heat and lack of coffee :D

Answer (score 0):

When compering strings use query arguments:

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query(
          Login_Table, 
          new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_USERNAME }, 
          KEY_USERNAME + "=?", 
          new String[] {name}, 
          null, 
          null, 
          null);
```